# puppet and aws module install issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, puppet

i tried puppet opensource but unable to use aws , it does not have aws sub command.

```
$puppet help node_aws

Error: Could not load help for the face node_aws.
Please check the error logs for more information.

Detail: "Could not find Puppet Face node_aws"

Error: Try 'puppet help help help' for usage
```

so i installed the module

```
$puppet module install puppetlabs-cloud_provisioner

Notice: Preparing to install into /etc/puppet/modules ...

Notice: Created target directory /etc/puppet/modules

Notice: Downloading from https://forge.puppetlabs.com ...

Notice: Installing -- do not interrupt ...

/etc/puppet/modules

└── puppetlabs-cloud_provisioner (v1.1.4)
```

but now i am getting the following error.

```
$puppet node_aws

Error: Could not autoload puppet/face/node_aws/create: cannot load such file -- guid

Error: Could not parse application options: Could not autoload puppet/face/node_aws/create: cannot load such file -- guid

$puppet help node_aws

Error: Could not autoload puppet/face/node_aws/create: cannot load such file -- guid
Error: Could not load help for the face node_aws.
Please check the error logs for more information.

Detail: "Could not autoload puppet/face/node_aws/create: cannot load such file -- guid"

Error: Try 'puppet help help help' for usage

**$puppet help**

Error: Could not autoload puppet/face/node/init: cannot load such file -- guid

Error: Could not autoload puppet/face/node_aws/create: cannot load such file -- guid
```

Regards

Suyash Jain

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the guid gem:

With gem tool run :

`$ gem install guid`